# Symfony 4 Dependency Injection: Inject into object while creating it in code

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm creating a `NavigationBuilder` class for my backend. With it, I should be able to add navigation items and then get the html (similar to Symfony's FormBuilder). It is used in a Twig Extension Function.

I have an `interface` and `abstract` class for a navigation item (e.g. Nav Link, Divider, Heading, etc.) and I'm creating child classes for these specific items.

For some of these nav items (Link) I need the Symfony `Router` or `RequestStack` and I want to inject it into the abstract class so I don't have to pass it as an argument to the constructor of every child class I need it in.

I tried using the method of injecting it with setter methods, because I thought Symfony would do it automatically whenever I create a new object, but obviously that isn't the case.

The `NavigationItem` class:

```php
namespace App\...\Navigation;

use App\...\NavigationItemInterface;
use Symfony\...\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\...\Request;

abstract class NavigationItem implements NavigationItemInterface {

  private $router;
  private $request;

  final public function setRouter(UrlGeneratorInterface $router): self {
    $this->router = $router;
    return $this;
  }

  final public function setRequest(Request $request): self {
    $this->request = $request;
    return $this;
  }

  final public function matchesCurrentRoute(String $route): Bool {
    return $this->getRequest()->get('_route') == $route;
  }

  /** ... **/
}
```

My `service.yaml` file:

```
App\...\NavigationItem:
        class: App\...\NavigationItem
        calls:
            - method: setRequest
              arguments:
                - '@request_stack'
            - method: setRouter
              arguments:
                - '@router'
```

I imagine it to work like this:

```php
$builder = new NavigationBuilder();
$builder
  ->addItem( new HeaderItem('A Heading') ) // No need for injection
  ->addItem( new LinkItem('Title', 'route') ) // NEED for injection
->build(); // Returns html
```

I get this error code:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined property: App...\DashboardItem::$router").**

Comment: I think you will need access to kernel di container and get router instance from there. Symfony supports autowiring functionaltiy only for controllers and services not general classes. This is my understanding

Comment: I would personally suggest you use KnpMenuBundle https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html or dig into it's source code to see how they handle it https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

Comment: The php new operator knows nothing about the di container.  So your basic hope is, well, hopeless.  Your nav builder should be a service and injected where needed.  Then the builder itself can take care of creating things like menu items and injecting the request as needed.

Comment: @Cerad Hey, thank you for your answer! Yes, this is my new approach. Create my NavigationBuilder class and inject it as a service to my Twig Extension class.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare a property as `private` only the class itself, but no child class can use it (directly, that is). declare it `protected` (talking about the `router` property in your abstract class) see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

apparently that's not the only problem, and I suppose you confuse dependency injection with auto-wiring. dependency injection only means, that an object doesn't create it's own dependencies, but instead they are from the outside/caller via parameters (in constructor, setters, or specific calls).

auto-wiring works in symfony by either fetching an object from the container (however, [by default you always get the same object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html). but there are ways to [define a factory or the option to always retrieve a new object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html), possibly, not quite sure).

Comment: Right, I did forget about visibility but I don't think it solves my initial problem. '**Call to a member function on null.**' It says when I try accessing the `$router` property of an item.

Comment: @Fabian I think you confuse dependency injection with auto-wiring/auto-configuration. If I was in your shoes, I would make the abstract class into a factory and let it produce headeritems and linkitems (or multiple factories, for that matter). auto-wiring/auto-configuration only works with parameters when the object / call is done by the framework.